# Laravel Query Builder - How to get only the last records matching query

Tags: mysql, arrays, laravel-5.1

Using Laravel 5.1 I have a stocks table with ticker and company name in a one-to-many relationship with a price table containing quote prices updated every 15 minutes. Can anyone enlighten me on the best way to get just the latest quote returned from the join of the two tables? Maybe another solution that I have not thought of? Here is my join that returns this for every stock and price in the database.

```
$quotes = DB::table('stocks')
    ->join('stock_prices', 'stocks.id', '=', 'stock_prices.stock_id')
    ->get();
return $quotes;
```

Which returns

```
[
{
"id": 25,
"symbol": "MSFT",
"last_price": "53.60",
},
{
"id": 25,
"symbol": "MSFT",
"last_price": "54.80",
},
{
"id": 30,
"symbol": "BA",
"last_price": "144.74",
},
{
"id": 30,
"symbol": "BA",
"last_price": "145.60",
},
]
```

Migrations

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('stock_prices', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->decimal('last_price', 6, 2);
        $table->decimal('net_change', 6, 2);
        $table->decimal('percent_change', 4, 2);
        $table->decimal('open', 6, 2);
        $table->decimal('high', 6, 2);
        $table->decimal('low', 6, 2);
        $table->decimal('close', 6, 2);
        $table->integer('volume');
        $table->integer('stock_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table  ->foreign('stock_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('stocks')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}    

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('stocks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('symbol');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->boolean('confirmed');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

So what would be the best way to get it to just return the last updated price for every stock? Either with working with the returned array or a new Laravel query builder? Or an Eloquent solution?

I have spent 2 days searching and banging my head against the wall so any help will be GREATLY appreciated.

Side notes: I plan to wipe out everything older than 30 days so the table will not be extremely large. Also while hacking through the array with some of the Laravel helpers I some times get an error saying it is not an array but an object and some times will say it is not an object but an array. Bonus points for explaining that to me.

Comment: I should probably add ... the table has other columns including the standard timestamps. I just shortened it here to save space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The raw query that could get you the most recent stock price per stock looks something like:

```
select s.id, s.symbol, sp.price, sp.updated from (
    select stock_id, max(updated) last_updated
    from   stock_price
    group by stock_id
) q
join stock_price sp on (q.stock_id = sp.stock_id and q.last_updated = sp.updated)
join stock s on (sp.stock_id = s.id)
;
```

Gets the most recent record in stock_price per stock, then joins back to stock_price to get price and joins to stock to get symbol.

Using the query builder:

```
$groupBy = DB::table('stock_price')
->selectRaw('stock_id, max(updated) as last_updated')
->groupBy('stock_id');

$quotes = DB::table( DB::raw("({$groupBy->toSql()}) as q") )
->selectRaw('s.id, s.symbol, sp.price, sp.updated')
->mergeBindings($groupBy)
->join('stock_price as sp', function ($join) {
    $join->on('q.stock_id', '=', 'sp.stock_id')
         ->on('q.last_updated', '=', 'sp.updated');
})
->join('stock as s', 'q.stock_id', '=', 's.id')
->get();
```

A bit long in the tooth, and may be preferable to use raw sql.

Comment: Wow!  Thank you so much!! I tweaked the query builder example (really just needed to put a few of the proper table and column names in place) and it worked like a charm. I will need to learn more about using RAW and MAX with Laravel. That was the missing pieces in what I was trying. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

you can use **orderBy** :

```
$quotes = DB::table('stocks')
->join('stock_prices', 'stocks.id', '=', 'stock_prices.stock_id')
->orderBy('updated_at','desc')
->get();
return $quotes;
```

Comment: Thanks I get this error.   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'updated_at' in order clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `stocks` inner join `stock_prices` on `stocks`.`id` = `stock_prices`.`stock_id` order by `updated_at` desc)  And if I get that to work wouldn't they just be ordered? I would still need to figure out how to pull the last quote for each ticker.

Comment: @BrioDev can we see your database ?

Comment: do you have created_at and updated_at field on your table? can you show your migration file to us?

Comment: Yes the standard timestamps are on each table. Local Laravel Homestead setup so no, I guess you wouldn't be able to access the database.  I could put up the migration I guess but everything as far as relations is working properly. I just don't know enough SQL to know how to write the query so it works in Laravel. I had thought about creating a separate table just to store the latest updates and then updating that table instead of adding to it but it seemed like a extra writes if there was a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use raw sql query with laravel. It will return result as collection of object. This code is based on, "When prices are updated then,  new records are inserted in `stock_prices` table".

```
$sql = "SELECT st.*, stp1.*
FROM stocks st
JOIN stock_prices stp1 ON (st.id = stp1.stock_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN stock_prices stp2 ON (st.id = stp2.stock_id AND 
    (stp1.created_at < stp2.created_at OR stp1.created_at = stp2.created_at AND stp1.id < stp2.id))
WHERE stp2.id IS NULL";       

$result = DB::select(DB::raw($sql));
return $result;
```

I have tested it with small data and return exact result. Please check with your data.

Comment: Thank you!!  Yes it works perfectly and returns the complete row. Not only that but I now know how to add a SQL query in Laravel and bypass the query builder. It is much easier to research pure SQL !!  Both answers were very helpful and i appreciate both of your time. Saw @JRD  first and sorry I can not mark them both as correct.